# SvelteKit async function load not working or Firebase onAuthStateChanged cannot be made blocking

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, svelte, sveltekit

I am building a website with SvelteKit. My auth provider is Firebase. I am trying to protect some pages with Authentication, so I am programming an auth listener in `__layout.svelte`. However, no matter how I try, I can't seems to pass the Auth Status from the `context module` to my `script`, this is my code:

__layout.svelte

```
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    import type { User } from 'firebase/auth';
    import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
    import { auth } from "$lib/scripts/firebaseStart";

    export async function load() {
        let authUser: User|boolean = await getAuthUser();
        async function getAuthUser() {
            await onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
                // let authUser: User|undefined;
                if (user) {
                    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
                    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
                    authUser = user;
                    console.log(authUser); // logs authUser out as I expected it to
                    // ...
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    // ...
                    authUser = false;
                }
            });
            return authUser;
        }

        return {
            props: { authUser }
        };
    }
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    export let authUser: User|boolean;
    console.log(authUser); // logs undefined and executed before the above console log
</script>
```

The conclusion I get is that the code in `script` tag is executed before the `context=module` could return the props. How do I make the code in the context module 'blocking'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load` always runs before the component is created, your code is incorrect.

[`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authonauthstatechanged) is *not* awaitable and returns an unsubscribe function instead. Also, you should either set the local `authUser` variable *or* return it from the function, doing both is unnecessary/confusing.

You can turn `onAuthStateChanged` into something that *can* be awaited by using the `Promise` constructor like this:

```js
export async function load() {
    const authUser: User | boolean = await getAuthUser();

    function getAuthUser() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            onAuthStateChanged(
                auth,
                user => resolve(user ? user : false)
            );
        });
    }

    return {
        props: { authUser }
    };
}
```

Note that `onAuthStateChanged` can be called multiple times and this only captures the first change. If you want to continuously track the auth state you should update a store.